# how to alter a subproject setting in an sbt-release step

Tags: scala, sbt

I use the `sbt-release` plugin for a couple of projects. One step I use is `docker:publish` for `sbt-native-packager` to push an image to Docker hub.

`sbt-native-packager` relies on the `dockerUpdateLatest` setting to decide whether to update the `latest` tag. The default is `false`, and if it is `true` it will update `latest`.

For one project, that has no sub projects under root, I am able to use a custom `ReleaseStep` to change that setting depending on if I am releasing a `SNAPSHOT`, i.e. I do not want to update the `latest` tag if the version ends in `SNAPSHOT`.

```
lazy val setDockerReleaseSettings = ReleaseStep(action = oldState => {
  // dockerUpdateLatest is set to true if the version is not a SNAPSHOT
  val extracted = Project.extract(oldState)
  val v = extracted.get(Keys.version)
  val snap = v.endsWith("SNAPSHOT")
  if (!snap) extracted
      .appendWithSession(Seq(dockerUpdateLatest := true), oldState)
  else oldState
})
```

The above works for that project.

For the other project, there are multiple projects aggregated under root. I would like to do something like

```
lazy val setDockerReleaseSettings = ReleaseStep(action = oldState => {
  // dockerUpdateLatest is set to true if the version is not a SNAPSHOT
  val extracted = Project.extract(oldState)
  val v = extracted.get(Keys.version)
  val snap = v.endsWith("SNAPSHOT")
  if (!snap) extracted
      .appendWithSession(Seq(dockerUpdateLatest in api := true, dockerUpdateLatest in portal := true), oldState)
  else oldState
})
```

But it does not seem to work. I also tried `dockerUpdateLatest in Global`, and `dockerUpdateLatest in root` to no avail. Any ideas how to alter `dockerUpdateLatest` in these sub projects?

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve it with `set every dockerUpdateLatest := true`. I made a custom ReleaseStep like so

```
lazy val createSetDockerUpdateLatestCommand = ReleaseStep(action = state => {
  // dockerUpdateLatest is set to true if the version is not a SNAPSHOT
  val snap = Project.extract(state).get(Keys.version).endsWith("SNAPSHOT")

  val setDockerUpdateLatest = if (!snap)
    Command.command("setDockerUpdateLatest") {
      "set every dockerUpdateLatest := true" ::
      _
    }
  else
    Command.command("setDockerUpdateLatest") {
      "" ::
      _
    }

  state.copy(definedCommands = state.definedCommands :+ setDockerUpdateLatest)
})
```

Then I run `setDockerUpdateLatest`